# Unreal Engine 5: place cameras on a hemisphere

Tags: c++, trigonometry, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have a hemisphere with radius 250. Located on the edge of the hemisphere (15 degrees above the base/horizon), I have 7 equally spaced points (i.e., 1 point every 360/7 degrees).

Using Unreal Engine 5, I want to place camera at each of those 7 points such that their FoV is perpendicular/orthogonal to the surface of the sphere.

Given camera number (1,2,3...7) and the radius of the hemisphere (250), what function will place the cameras in the correct position and facing the correct direction?

A blueprint or C++ would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can SpawnActor at those locations. Shouldn't be any trouble there. for setting the angle you can use this function to get a vector pointing outwards on the sphere: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Vector/GetUnitDirection_Vector/

You will need to use the center of the hemisphere and the camera location for setting the angle